# Swap problems after upgrading from 14.04 to 16.06

Tags: boot, 16.04, upgrade, swap, cryptsetup

After upgrading Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04 booting started to be very slow.
It seems to be a problem with swap partitions. Bellow I attach some details.

cat /var/log/boot.log

```
[FAILED] Failed to activate swap /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1.
See 'systemctl status "dev-mapper-ubunt...\x2dvg\\x2dswap_1.swap"' for details.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Swap.
...
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device dev-di...\x2db1dc\x2dae7fb1c172e6.device.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Cryptography Setup for cryptswap1.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /dev/mapper/cryptswap1.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Encrypted Volumes.
```

cat /etc/fstab

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=d57910fd-a1ae-4721-8da0-af0677f5a869 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

cat /etc/ctypttab

```
sda5_crypt UUID=cc64c6e4-f704-4f8e-8801-c9fe847b99c1 none luks,discard
cryptswap1 UUID=7ad77809-b29c-4434-b1dc-ae7fb1c172e6 /dev/urandom swap,cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256
```

lsblk

```
NAME                    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                       8:0    0 238,5G  0 disk  
├─sda1                    8:1    0   243M  0 part  /boot
├─sda2                    8:2    0     1K  0 part  
└─sda5                    8:5    0 238,2G  0 part  
  └─sda5_crypt          252:0    0 238,2G  0 crypt 
    ├─ubuntu--vg-root   252:1    0 206,6G  0 lvm   /
    └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 252:2    0  31,7G  0 lvm   
sr0                      11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

cat /proc/swaps

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
```

ll /dev/mapper/

```
crw-------  1 root root 10, 236 sie 23 14:29 control
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 sie 23 14:29 sda5_crypt -> ../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 sie 23 14:29 ubuntu--vg-root -> ../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 sie 23 14:29 ubuntu--vg-swap_1 -> ../dm-2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to start Ubuntu from CD or USB, then select the option "try ubuntu", run **GParted.**

If required delete the old swap partition and create a new swap partition.

/etc/fstab should have a line similar to this

```
UUID=some-unique-id-for-the-partition swap swap defaults 0 0
```

to get the unique id run`blkid` in terminal